# How can I access my posts on my wordpress site, now I've lost the domain name for it?

Tags: posts

I wrote some posts for a wordpress site I've got, unforunately I couldn't renew the domain name in time, so I want to access the text in those posts, and put it into my new site, how can I do that? I can access the site via my cpanel and IP for the site, and I can see the WP files there but I don't know where the post data is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posts in WordPress are stored in a `MySQL database`. There are several ways to access a `MySQL database`, but the most common way is that your web host provides access to a tool called `PHPMyAdmin`. This is a web application that allows you to manage your `MySQL database`, including making an `SQL dump`. An SQL dump is a file with the data of your `MySQL database`. It is possible to import the `SQL dump` in your new database.

Basically, when you install WordPress on your new domain, you should be able to reset your new database and import your `SQL dump` again.

For information on how to do this, contact your web host - some use other software than `PHPMyAdmin`.

Good luck!